# Using Hbase Data To Develop a Web Application In Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, hbase

I want to create a web application using hbase data. I researched a lot but
i don't know how to start. Can anybody send me the use cases or sample
template for this integration. This could help me a lot.

Regards,

Ravikanth

Answer (score 0):

Note - your question is too broad and may be closed. This is just to help you get started.

You may want to look at [`massive_record`](https://github.com/CompanyBook/massive_record) as an ORM for hbase. Other parts could be exactly as you would do with any backend.

Refer to [this presentation](http://www.slideshare.net/thillerson/rails-on-hbase) for a walkthrough of using Rails with hBase as backend.